# NullPointerException при переходе на новую Activity

Tags: java, android, activity

Пытаюсь по нажатии на Button перейти в новую Activity, но система выдает ошибку и приложение вылетает.

Вот logcat вместе с ошибкой.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.washcar/com.example.washcar.second_activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2669)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2730)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1481)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6144)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.washcar.second_activity.onCreate(second_activity.java:104)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6722)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2622)
``
```

Comment: Это не баг, а ошибка, название которой нужно приложить к вопросу

Comment: Изменил вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка указана этой строке:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

Невозможно вызвать метод `setOnClickListener()` на нулевую ссылку объекта. Значит, не присвоили переменной типа `Button` значения.

Примерный код в Activity:

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
```

Тогда в файле разметки должно быть что-нибудь подобное:

```
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/my_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Кнопка" />
```

Вместо `my_button` можно написать любой другой идентификатор.
Вместо `Button` может быть любой вид.